# Scheduler in Laravel 5.4, Crontab is not working automatically

Tags: php, laravel

When I run 'php artisan schedule:run' in terminal, it's Working perfectly. when I configure my crontab to execute it automatically it has no effect. Cron is not Working.

Kernel.php

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        Log::info('Cron Started');
        $test=Example::orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get();
    })->everyMinute();
```

I Runned this Script also :

```
   * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

While i using `crontab -e` in CMD

```
  No crontab for root - using an empty one No modification made
```

Comment: Please clarify: you have problems setting up the Cron job? Your crontab is empty, you need to add the second piece of code to your crontab.

Comment: Yes I have a problem to setting up a cron job. What is mean Second piece of code, i can't understand

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job on how to setup a cron job. You say you "Runned this Script also". But how, because every 3 that line you need to add to the crontab. All the asterisks are used by Cron in determining when to run the job, in this case every minute.